# how to make Redis expire event only send to one client

Tags: redis

If two same clients connect to a redis server,and register same listener on a key expire event,can I make redis server only send a expire event to one client ,not two clients

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that with [Redis Keyspace Notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications). Keyspace Notifications is just a special case of [Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub). And Pub/Sub do not allow you to do this.